# Cannot define in stdafx.h

Tags: c++

When doing this in VS 2010 sp1 in stdafx.h file:

```
#include <memory>

#define ptr_type std::shared_ptr
```

I'm getting an error:

```
fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Comment: @honk try it and'll see.

Comment: @honk: you cannot typedef uninstantiated templates. Well, at least not with current compilers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected end of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903100/unexpected-end-of-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In your .cpp file, you need to put `#include "stdafx.h"` as your first line of code. This is for precompiled header support.</strike>

Edit: I'm wrong; the error I'm thinking of is "*C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header*".