# Unexpected end of a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When trying in VS2010 Ultimate sp1 to #include ANY std header inside "stdafx.h" I'm getting an error:
*fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found*
Does anyone else experience this or is there something wrong with my installation?

Edit
My main looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <_dbdao.h>//if I remove this line it will compile
```

stdafx.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

AND THERE IS NOTHING MORE

Comment: Or turn `stdafx.h` off - do it the non-proprietary way.

Comment: (continuation of his other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892896/cannot-define-in-stdafx-h)

Comment: Clearly this has been a problem for a while... Solve it by elimination. Comment out stuff until it compiles, and then figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @tenfour the problem is that when I create new project and then in stdafx.h try to include anything I'm getting the error. The project is new and clean, there is no code except what VS puts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why the Visual Studio Compiler gives this error. [MSDN explains it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4exw7xyc%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> The compiler reached the end of a source file without resolving a
>   construct. The code may be missing one of the following elements:
>
> A closing brace
>   A closing parenthesis
>   A closing comment marker (*/)
>   A semicolon

My guess is that it's not really related to the stdafx.h file, but rather you have a class somewhere like this:

```
class A {
...
}
```

without the semicolon after `}`. It has to be

```
class A {
...
};
```

If this does not solve it you should do what [tenfour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402169/tenfour) is suggesting. Eliminate until it compiles to find out what causes it.

Comment: I'm creating BRAND NEW project, nothing is there except what VS puts. Nothing is there.

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my OP I'm getting "fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found"

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty project? are you choosing to create a pre-compiled project or an empty project? what does it say at Options > Project Options > C/C++ > Precompiled headers (I think it's located here, don't have VS in front of me..)

Comment: what does your `main.cpp` look like?

Comment: Not sure why you are including _dbdao.h. It's not a standard file (as in, not usually included in the template by VS) and is probably not needed. But as you say, if you remove that file the error disappears. So in that file is an error as described by what MSDN says. You should take a look inside that file and look for missing closing braces, closing parenthesis, closing comment marker (*/) or semicolon. one way to find it is to comment out big chunks and then slowly uncommenting. Useful shortcuts here are `Ctrl - K, Ctrl - C` and `Ctrl - K, Ctrl - U` (comment/uncomment selection)

Comment: it happens with ANY file. Not just dbdao

Answer (score 0):

If you use precompiled headers, you need to include stdafx.h in every source file in your project.
Otherwise it can lead to the error message you quoted here.

(This answer is based on the given information)